# Sign Up/Log In Form PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Good day!

I have been looking for various solutions on the web but I haven't passed by a single one to solve my problem

Basically I have been making a login system with a registration feature, and everything is working well except when I try to register, it doesn't enter into the database that I have made. Then I tried inserting values into my table, and tried logging in, but all it does was log in even though I did the password wrong.

Here's the database:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| studID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname    | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname    | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address  | varchar(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
<style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
<div align="center">
<p><img src="images/welcome.jpg" /></p>
  <table id="title">
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
<p>New here? <a href="signup.php">Register!</a></p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");

session_start(); 

$username=($_POST['username']);
$password=($_POST['password']);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM student WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");

$count=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($count==0){
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:success.php");
} else {
  echo 'Wrong Username or Password! Return to <a href="index.html">login</a>';
  }
?>
```

and db.php

```
<?php  
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ella');
     if (!$conn)
    {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("studrecord", $conn);
?>
```

signup.php (it's quite long, will cut some unnecessary parts)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.html">
  <table id="title">
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include 'db.php';

                    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
                            $lname=$_POST['lname'];                 
                    $address=$_POST['address'];
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
                    $password=$_POST['password'];

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO student(fname,lname,address,username,password) 
         VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address','$username','$password')"); 
            }
?>
</...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if login system is working well and not register then why you show your login.php and not signup.php ?

Comment: oh, right-- totally overlooked that. thanks for reminding!

Comment: mysql is deprecated,  try mysqli or pdo

Comment: session_register("username") is deprecated use $_SESSION["username"]

Comment: EVERYTHING in your script is bad, wrong, extremely outdated and totally insecure. I really dont want to offend you, but you should not use this script! Pleeease get a professional script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `signup.php` document, it looks like your form action takes you back to the `index.php` page. That means the logic of the following PHP code never actually takes place. Use this:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
```

instead of `<form action="index.html">`.

Try changing the form action to the page itself and see if you get data inserted into your table.

Some side notes:

- As others have said here, the [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) commands are deprecated in current versions of PHP, so either mysqli or PDO would be better to use.
- Instead of asking for `'SELECT count(*) FROM student WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'`, it might be better to just ask for the result rows themselves by replacing `COUNT(*)` with simply `*`. You may then use `mysqli_num_rows` to count the rows.
- I hope I'm not missing anything, but I am a little confused by the logic on your `index.php` page. You say

  ```
  if($count==0){
      // Register a session ...
  } else { 
      // Wrong password/username...
  }
  ```

  where I think you mean `if($count > 0)`, because you want a row to exist with that username/password combination.
- If you plan on using database queries extensively in your project, I highly recommend reading the documentation on [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in particular. This will allow you to largely avoid SQL injection issues and also to more easily prepare flexible queries.

Good luck in your endeavors!

Comment: @EllaDurban Any time. There's a great SO post about prepared statements [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496). It's still relevant, even though it was answered five years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the count query to this. Also stay well away from mysql_* functions as they are depreciated.

```
<?php
include("db.php");

session_start(); 

$username=($_POST['username']);
$password=($_POST['password']);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==0){
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:success.php");
} else {
  echo 'Wrong Username or Password! Return to <a href="index.html">login</a>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: "Then I tried inserting values into my table, and tried logging in, but all it does was log in even though I did the password wrong."

Answer (score 0):

you are login with wrong password because you are not checking if exist in database , change your code to this.

change this

```
   $count=mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if($count==0){
 session_register("username");
 session_register("password");
 header("location:success.php");
 } else {
   echo 'Wrong Username or Password! Return to <a href="index.html">login</a>';
 }
```

to

```
     $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($count > 0){
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:success.php");
 } else {
   echo 'Wrong Username or Password! Return to <a href="index.html">login</a>';
 }
```

in your register yfile you are checking with same name of login and signup

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                      ^^^-------name
```

change the name of register input .

to this

```
    if (isset($_POST['register_form']))
```

and put it in your form.

and change your form

```
      <form action="index.html">
```

to

```
     <form action="signup.php" method ="POST" name="register_form">
```

Comment: Thanks, the login is working well now. I edited the register file as you said, but any of my inputs as I signup still can't be inserted into database.

Comment: you just change action to `signup.php` because you was using index.html in action and like that should work everything :). wish i could help you.sorry i was not here

Answer (score 0):

Not an awnser to your question but change

```
$username=($_POST['username']);
$password=($_POST['password']);
```

to

```
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: he is not using mysqli

Comment: ah, yes you are correct. He should though as mysql_* functions are deprecated.